# Embedding Powershell v2.0 in .NET app on Windows 8 RTM

Tags: .net, powershell

Im getting the following error when trying to run hosted powershell scripts before upgrading from Windows 7 I never got this error.

> The following error occurred while loading the extended type data
>   file:  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2977) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2984) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2991) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2998) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3005) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject.

I have applied the following in App.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Management.Automation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The solution is to do the following, rather than only adding a block for only System.Management.Automation as suggested by the posts I read, you need to add one for all referenced PS assemblies.

```
  <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Management.Automation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

Comment: Perfect -- this was the missing additional information from this post on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060460/using-powershell-2-as-default-version-on-windows-8/

Comment: With Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1, adding these lines to the `<runtime>` section of `%APPDATA%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\devenv.exe.config` solves the problem.

Comment: It failed for me in VS2015, and this advice has been helpful for it. Just open `c:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config` and add the same lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, from time to time Visual Studio regenerates this file and the change is lost, so you have to put it back.

Comment: almost 4 years later and this is still the only solution?

Comment: Added %APPDATA%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_311b6a3\devenv.exe.co‌​nfig

I have a 15.0 folder and a 15.0_311b6a3 (????) folder.

Working!!!  Thank you for the post.

Comment: 18-Feb-2018 - The above "solution" has no effect when running on Windows 10 using VS 15.5.6 -- Basically, I am unable to use NuGet with Visual studio, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837473/visual-studio-2017-unable-to-initialize-powershell-host-day-1-and-2

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in VS 2015 Update 3.

I must remove the folder:

```
%APPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
```

and then add into:

```
c:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.‌​0\devenv.exe.config
```

in section:

```
<runtime> 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
```

the following lines:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Management.Automation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I lost two days searching for solutions... thanks MS :-/

Comment: I just updated the config file without deleting and folders and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

above answer did not work for me, i fixed the problem by removing the %APPDATA%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ folder.

Upon restarting VS this folder is recreated and the package manager console works again. A little crude but it does the job.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! This is the only thing that worked. Happened on both my PC's after updating to v3.... Many kudos and thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Not a good idea. This will also remove lots of the installed extensions.

Comment: Actually it wasn't helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

After trying the solution in the accepted answer and getting tired of Visual Studio resetting the file, I reinstalled VS 2015 from scratch and haven't had the problem since. If you find the issue persists, the nuclear option is definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Install the appropriate version of PowerShell for your OS:

- Windows XP SP2 / Vista / 2003 / 2008 - PowerShell v1.0
- Windows XP SP3 / Vista SP1 / 7 / 2003 SP2 / 2008 R2 - PowerShell v2.0
- Windows 7 SP1 / 8 / 2008 SP1 / 2008 R2 SP1 / 2012 - PowerShell v3.0
- Windows 7 SP1 / 8.1 / 2008 R2 SP1 / 2012 / 2012 R2 - PowerShell v4.0
- Windows 7 SP1 / 8.1 / 2008 R2 SP1 / 2012 / 2012 R2 - PowerShell v5.0
  (as part of Windows Management Framework (WMF) 5.0)

Comment: Windows XP SP2 / Vista / 2003 / 2008 - PowerShell v1.0  

Windows XP SP3 / Vista SP1 / 7 / 2003 SP2 / 2008 R2 - PowerShell v2.0  

Windows 7 SP1 / 8 / 2008 SP1 / 2008 R2 SP1 / 2012 - PowerShell v3.0  

Windows 7 SP1 / 8.1 / 2008 R2 SP1 / 2012 / 2012 R2 - PowerShell v4.0  

Windows 7 SP1 / 8.1 / 2008 R2 SP1 / 2012 / 2012 R2 - PowerShell v5.0 (as part of Windows Management Framework (WMF) 5.0)

Comment: To install in the native OS releases, go to:  

 -Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features or the equivalent,   

 -then click on the 'Turn Windows features on or off' link,  

 -click on 'Features' in the MMC tree view in the left-side navigation pane,   

 -then click the 'Add Features' link on the right side of the 'Features Summary' pane accordion child section   

 -Finally, check the checkbox for Windows PowerShell Integrated  Scripting Environment (ISE) or equivalent (name may differ in different OSes)

Comment: See the original release versions and matching OSes here, in the 'Versions' section:
<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell>