# NuGet Package Manager Console unable to load PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

After performing an in place upgrade from Windows 7 Pro to 8 Pro I have been unable to get NuGet's package manager console to run in Visual Studio 2012 Pro. The error I receive is:

```
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2977) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2984) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2991) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2998) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3005) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The term 'Get-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have searched for the last several days for ways to fix this but have been coming up completely empty. I have tried all of these with no avail:

- Disabling all Visual Studio add ons
- Resetting all settings
- Reinstalling Visual Studio
- Repairing Visual Studio
- Starting PowerShell before Visual Studio (Does this just mean launch PowerShell and then launch Visual Studio?)
- Running both PowerShell and Visual Studio as admin
- Running Visual Studio in safe mode
- Setting Power Shell ExecutionProperty to unrestricted

Visual Studio has been exhibiting other odd behaviors such as consistently crashing while trying to add a Click event to XAML on a specific page as well, and because of this my gut says it's not really Power Shell or NuGet but an issue with my OS/Visual Studio.

Unless someone has a solution I think I'm down to just doing a clean install of Windows 8 and hoping that that fixes it.

Answer (score 4):

I found this issue which is very similar to yours:

[Embedding Powershell v2.0 in .NET app on Windows 8 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638289/embedding-powershell-v2-0-in-net-app-on-windows-8-rtm)

Can you try the solution on that question to see if it fixes it?

Comment: I found that method also and tried it with no luck. I finally gave up and just clean installed Win8 which fixed it obviously.