# NuGet fails with VS 2015 update 2

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

When I open Visual Studio, the Package Manager Console has red text:

> The following error occurred while loading the extended type data
>   file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3007) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject.

***Repeats 4 more times ***

The term 'Get-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

This happened after applying VS 2015 Update 2 and some Windows 10 updates. My PowerShell at the path above is version 5; in my Windows features I also have version 2.0 installed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [known issues](https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/Known-Issues) with the version of Nuget that shipped with Visual Studio Update 2. Trying updating to the latest version of Nuget (version as of this post 3.4.3).

**Update**

Specifically related to [your issue](https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/Known-Issues#user-content-opening-package-manager-console-fails-with-objectsecurity-exception), from nuget know issues, [suggested fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638289/embedding-powershell-v2-0-in-net-app-on-windows-8-rtm).

Comment: I updated Nuget and added dependentAssemblies to my dev config, but the problem is unchanged.